# Pull data from 17+ tabs into a master sheet within the same workbook

Tags: database

I have a workbook with a MASTER sheet.  This master sheet has columns A:P with different information needed in each cell. (House IDs are down Column A)

I have 17 tabs (all named by their HOUSE ID -ex DEN8) with the same cell structure in a template with the information for each of those houses.  I need to pull the data for the columns to the MASTER sheet from each of the cells in these house ID tabs.  Individually is exhausting. I know there has to be something, but I am sure it is well above my head.  (I will need detailed information on what to put in what cells and how - remember the "novice" part of my experience - I'm really trying to learn and may take a more advanced class at some point since my new position requires a LOT of data management).

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: If I am able to attach a sample workbook somehow I can... just let me know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can type = in any cell, then click on another workbook.  Then click on a cell with in that workbook, and now the information will be linked over.

Additionally, if your going to be doing this a lot you probably want to write a macro using VBA.

Inside of excel there is a macro recorder, and you can record a sequence of step into a macro.  You will then have to go back and tweak the automatically generated code to get it to be 100% the way you want it.  A few things may not be caught by the macro recorder and you may have to modify the code yourself.

Check the indicated **Developer** box under File->options

[image: active developer mode]

When you go back to the main interface you will now see this.

[image: Developer tab]
**Record macro** is visible here.

If you spend enough time developing the macro, you could eventually get it to the point where you run your macro and all your work is done.

In the beginning I recommend recording multiple macros to make your code easier to troubleshoot.  If you make a few basic modifications you should be able to lump them altogether when your all done.

Eventually you should be able to write a FOR-NEXT loop to automatically cycle through all your workbooks.

Like so:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
     MsgBox ("test" + ws.Name)
     'Your computations for each sheet go here.  You need to reference each sheet using ws.
Next ws '
```

Honestly a database would probably make more sense long term, but I am trying to solve your short term problems.

Comment: So far over my head.  But the database sounds like it's a better option.  I've used Access a long time ago, is that my best option here for a beginner?

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the calculations you have to do.  To really excel you need either VBA for excel or SQL for access.  The pretty GUI in access only gets you so far.  So I would have to ask what kind of calculations are you doing?  Simple add,subtract,multiple, and divide or are there complex formulas involved?

Comment: Can I send you a blank of my spreadsheet and show you?  How could I do that?

Comment: @MJM1967 Normally, one put a copy on google drive or similar, and uses their "get a public link" option.  Then they paste the public link here.  Google, under **Share**, and restricted share and you will get an email if someone requests access and you can choose to allow it.

Comment: here is the workbook.  I will have probably 70-80 sites to add into the doc.  I need the information from each tab to automatically populate in the Overview sheet under it's line.  I did put the fx for each as I have it currently in my master workbook, but doing these line by line is insane for 70-80.  Hope you can help!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z-iPCNx0FhsE1JLNW4usD7dzyXkLhtDh/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107004756777892422503&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Were you able to access?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering about formulas or processing your trying to do?

Comment: Referring to Overview sheet cell c2, for you does that have the correct value or a $NAME? or similar error?

Comment: So assuming row one is actually working, You should be able to copy and paste the formulas from row 1 to row 2 changing the GRA5 to BBM2 and so on.  So is that what your trying to saving is copying and pasting all those formulas over?

Comment: in B2 on **OVERVIEW** place this formula  "=INDIRECT(A2&"!B12")"  then use copy and paste to paste the formula into all the cells in column B.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes for the columns with simple formulas.  Column C, K and Q have complex functions. How would I do those?  
=CONCAT('AKH4'!$B$14," | ",'AKH4'!$G$12)
=IF('AKH4'!$B$35<>"",'AKH4'!$B$35,"NO")
=IF('AKH4'!$B$22<>"",'AKH4'!$B$22,"")

Comment: Simple modification can handle this: =CONCAT(INDIRECT(A2&"!$B$14")," | ", INDIRECT(A2&"!$G$12"))
and a IF statement can have **indirect** shoe horned into the formula.
=IF(INDIRECT(A2&"!$B$35")<>"",INDIRECT(A2&"!$B$35),"NO")

Comment: thank you SOOOOO much.  The sheet is working perfectly now.  And I learned some things!  Love to learn ;-)

Comment: @MJM1967  I am glad I could help.  I assume you will mark my answer as accepted and maybe upvote?  Never give up learning, I do it all the time.

Comment: The next thing you should start learning is called "5th normal form".  It is a 5 step process to get your data to into an uniform format.  You can use this in your next stage of development to setup a database.  In MS access or basically any database software there is some kind of view or forum to visually display the data anyway you want.  However, when the data is in a database your graph it, and study long terms patterns easier.  If the cost of fuel goes up 10% a year you can analyze the data to find out and plan for it long term.